# encased physics objects in unity 5?

Tags: blender, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set up a strange box in unity 3D. The problem is is that it blows apart when the game is run. I read somewhere it had something to do with rigid bodies overlapping, but I was not able to find a good resolution to the issue.

Below is a schematic of the box. The parts, labelled at the top, all have different component setups.

The handles (ha and hb) are parents to their boxhalves (ba and bb). The handles take care of gravity for the both of them by being a rigid body, and use a box collider. The boxes, because of their shape, uses a mesh collider.

The center piece (c) is parent to both of the stoppers (sa and sb). The center is the rigid body, while the stoppers use box colliders.

The idea was that the center piece would remain in the boxes, so if a player pulled one end of the box, that half would "extend" out to the stopper. When pushed back in, it would stop at the stopper. If two players help each end, they could both control the "stretch" of the box.

However, when running the game, the boxes immediately explode apart.

Any helpful advice would be wonderful!

[image]

Comment: You might get more in deph insights in another stack exchange site: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Seems possible that you might be running into an issue with concave colliders. Maybe splitting up your mesh colliders into convex hulls would help. There's also [this tool](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/4596) on the asset store that looks like it might have been designed for your situation.